# can't access id with getElementById and a var

Tags: javascript

I have a problem here, i can't get the id work:

```
var charCodeRange = {
 start: 65,
 end: 90
}

character = charCodeRange.start
nbr = 1;
id_case = String.fromCharCode(character) + nbr
```

When I use:

```
document.getElementById(id_case).onmouseover= myfunction()
```

It doesn't work. I know my function works cause it's ok when I put id_case = "A1"

An idea ?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Is the value of id_case correct if you output it before using it?

Comment: Does `id_case` value match with yout HTML element ID?

Comment: Debug it by adding a line: "console.log(id_case)" to make sure that says A1 like you think.

Comment: @JeffShaver—the OP is calling [*String.fromCharCode*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.3.2), which returns a string from the supplied *charCode* arguments.

Comment: The portions of the code above are on the same file? Are you sure the second part comes after the first one?

Comment: What is `myfunction`? Is that the complete script? Don't invoke it!

Comment: @Bergi
document.getElementById(id_case).onmouseover=function mouse_over() {
     document.getElementById(id_case).style.backgroundColor = "#E8DDFF";
     document.getElementById("txtbox_"+id_case).style.backgroundColor = "#E8DDFF";
    }

Comment: @ScottStafford
I'm on a webpage, I used alert and got A1

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
document.getElementById(id_case).onmouseover= myfunction()
```

with:

```
document.getElementById(id_case).onmouseover = myfunction;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have precised, I have myfunction() {The Function}

Comment: Unless `myfunction` returns a function reference, this is probably right.

Comment: @DavidBensoussan I know and see that `myfunction()` is a function. Try this and this will work for you

Comment: @metal_fan I tried, but I know the problme comes from here:
id_case = String.fromCharCode(character) + nbr

Answer (score 0):

I did a test, and it's working if I put this:

```
document.getElementById("A1").style.backgroundColor = "#E8DDFF";
```

but not if

```
stringtest = "A1"                          
document.getElementById(stringtest).style.backgroundColor = "#E8DDFF";
```

is used...

Comment: Still stuck :-(, any idea ?